# Access old mysql version from old server using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in the process of slowly duplicating an old system before replacing it entirely, and it involves creating a PHP script to check if there's a new record in the old database table, then update the equivalent new database table. Here's when I'm having an issue.

Whenever I connect to the old database, I always encounter the error `Not connected : Connection using old (pre-4.1.1) authentication protocol refused (client option 'secure_auth' enabled)`.

Here's my code right now (it was originally `PDO`,then used `mysqli_*`, and now this):

```
$dbpre = mysql_connect(REMOTE_DBHOST, REMOTE_DBUSERNAME, REMOTE_DBPASSWORD);
if (!$dbpre) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

I already did some research on this but most solution that I see involves a command line or MySQL GUI tool, but I can only use PHP. Any ideas what should I do?

Old database is using MySQL is 4.0.16, and I'm using PHP 5.6.11-1ubuntu3.1 and MySQL 5.6.28-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 on the new server.

---

**SOLUTION**
As per suggestion below, I created a username with no password, granting it with all permission. Anyway, this system is in a closed network, so there's no worry in being hacked by someone from the outside.

Comment: If you are replacing it, why did you move away from PDO and MySQLi...?

Comment: If your DB is on a shared hosting you may ask to their support to reset your password. Your issue should be due to an update in password hashing in MySQL 4.1.1

Comment: make a new user with access to whatever you need, __WITHOUT A PASSWORD__ , and make sure only truested IPs can access this account - or make a proxy for this account

Comment: @Qirel I am replacing it, and in the new system, I am using PDO. I was just trying all the possible ways to connect to an old database, including using the long depracated `mysql_connect`

Comment: @hanshenrik so I ended up using your suggestion since it's only accessible on a local network. can you put your suggestion as an answer so I can formally accept it? thank you so much

Comment: Mysqli can connect to the same databses as mysql, and PDO even more. I doubt choosing mysql over any of the others will make a difference. But as long as you figured it out, all is well! ;)

Comment: @Qirel agreed, and rest assured that I still used `mysqli_*` to connect now that's a workaround has been found. I was simply exhausting the options on how to connect to a database before I asked for help :)

Comment: Please remove `Solved` fro  your title and post the solution you found as a proper answer.